# How to fix this invalid syntax?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to make a game in python, and stack trace keeps coming up with 'invalid syntax'(those are the EXACT words of the stack trace, not me summing it up) at this line:

```
print('Look(1) | Bust down door with weapon(2)')
```

The cursor is always between the 'p' and the 'o' whenever I check it with ALT+X, regardless of where it
was before I checked it.

There are no syntax errors in that line that I can recognize. I was wondering if someone more experienced could help me?

These are the lines above and below that in case you think it's not that line itself that's causing the 
problem:

```
    print('You are in a dark and grimy dungeon. You see no windows, and a door. What\
would you like to do?')
    print('Look(1) | Bust down door with weapon(2)')
    act_umpteenth = input('>>> ')
    while act_umpteenth:
    [rest of code continues on here that I'm not bothered to copy and paste]
```

Edit: Solution found. The culprit was a close bracket behind a string that I was assigning to a variable a few lines up. I think I thought it was a print statement or something. :P I deleted it, and now the code works 100%. Thanks for suggesting that I look over the code for indentation/tab/spaces problems, even if it wasn't the problem, because otherwise I wouldn't have spotted the actual problem.

Comment: looks like you have unnecessary indentation. The prints should be at the same indent level

Comment: They are. I just copied and pasted it wrong onto the OP here. Sorry, I fixed it now. Do you know another reason why it's not working?

Comment: Obviously you are pasting some codes wrong, please be sure about your question.

Comment: Ok. can you edit the question with the exact error you get (the stack trace) and the relevant code ?

Comment: Is the first print statement on two lines?

Comment: I did copy and paste some codes wrong. It has since been fixed up. I think the fixed up version of the code relates to the question, and I've made my question clear. What are you unsure about? If you have any confusions relating to my question, because you think it's unclear or you would like to see more code, ask me.

Comment: @Volatility Yes it is.

Comment: try running it with `python -tt myscript.py` you are probably mixing tabs and spaces when you run it with the -tt command it will tell you about inconsistent indentation

Comment: @karthikr 'Invalid Syntax' is the exact error I got from the stack trace. That's exactly what it says :/ Well considering, the cursor keeps stopping between the 'p' and 'o' in the weapon, I consider that line, and perhaps the lines around it, the relevant code. So I think it's there already >.<

Comment: I assure you that the code you posted raises no SyntaxError. You're probably missing a closing brace somewhere.

Comment: Can you put the whole error output here, instead of just "Invalid Syntax"?  Include the stack trace and the cursor and such.

Comment: @Rawing wrong language ... it is 100% an indentation problem from OP mixing tabs and spaces ... but OP does not know how to run a python program from command prompt ...

Comment: @Rawing That was exactly the case! I accidentally put a close brace behind a string that I was assigning to a variable several lines up. (which weren't in the OP) It has since been fixed up, and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would just go and redo all your tabs. You can highlight all the code, and press Shift + Tab (you might have to do this multiple times) to back everything up to the left edge. Then you'll want to re-tab everything over in the proper way.

Comment: since OP does not know how to run a python script from command prompt to find where the indentation is broken I will concure that this is what OP needs to do +1

Comment: Thanks, reading the comments on yours helped me decide on this answer :-p

Answer (score 0):

try running it with

```
python -tt myscript.py
```

you are probably mixing tabs and spaces when you run it with the -tt command it will tell you about inconsistent indentation

fixing your indentation should resolve your issue

I figured I would put this as an answer even though it is really a comment

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm not really sure I understand what you mean. What's -tt myscript.py?

Comment: you have some .py file ... you normally execute with `python somescript.py` add the `-tt` option so its `python -tt somescript.py`

Comment: I still don't get what you mean. I'm writing the code in a module in IDLE. I normally execute(by execute I assume you mean open?) by clicking on the file in the place I've saved it. No idea what you mean by python somescript.py or adding the -tt option.

Comment: alternatively you can use an ide like notepad++, select all and use the option `file > edit > blank operations > tab to space`

Comment: basically your problem is that you have mixed tabs and spaces ... you need to execute the python script from the command line as ive shown ... I dont know how else I can help you ... `click start, click run, type "cmd", hit <enter>, type "cd directory\for\script", type "python -tt <myscriptname>.py"`